# I get an error when creating perspective box based on mouse position 3D effect in JS

Tags: javascript, null, onmousemove

I am following this site and the first example.

https://armandocanals.com/posts/CSS-transform-rotating-a-3D-object-perspective-based-on-mouse-position.html

I copied the code into VSC but get an error.

Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "onmousemove", mouseOverContainer is null
 http://127.0.0.1:5500/mhbox.js:19

[Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SuST.png)

Answer (score 0):

FACE PALM.  The script tag was loading before the div element in the HTML.  Just a reminder to think about when and where things load.